# Cypress login one time with before hook

Tags: cypress

I am trying to login one time with before hook and execute my all test cases .
But after execution of the  first(it) test others (it) test shows 401 error .When I reload page cy.reload() in second (it) , redirect to base url .

I also used preserve cookies https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies#Debug

What I do for this .

Comment: It will be helpful to check, if you share the implementation code?

Comment: If it is only having this issue on chrome or edge, then I might know the answer. Without showing us the code and the error, its hard to tell.